# iOS SOAP WCF calling issues - HTTP 415 error

Tags: ios, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am trying to send SOAP request but it is returning "HTTP 415 unsupported media" error.

below given is my code

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Envelope xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><Body><GetCity xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><SearchString></SearchString><SearchZone></SearchZone></GetCity></Body></Envelope>"];



NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ws.abcxyz.com/abcxyz1/Service1.svc?wsdl"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetCity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {

    NSMutableData *responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSLog(@"success %d", [responseData length]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"failed");
    //messageTextView.text=@"Failed";

}
```

Please let me know if i need to change anything.

Comment: what might be the issue? am i missing anything is this code??

Comment: what is to insert in to search tag and search zone

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 415 error- Unsupported Media Type

The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of
   the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource
   for the requested method.

Comment: @PrafulKadam you can make a cross check with API creator, that will be great to discuss about what media type match with server request.